# Get hour of day in Solidity?

Tags: time

What is the most simple way to get hour of the day in Solidity? Will this work? for example creating a condition that works only when it's past 17:00 during that day?

```
if(hour > 17) { //yay this is it }
```

Will this work?

Comment: Know the time it's an "real world" information so that you will need to use oracles for that. I've never tried before, but you can take a look on here: https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime

Comment: there is block.timestamp which is seconds since a date in 1970

i reckon another solution would be
uint8((timestamp / 60 / 60) % 24); but nto sure if this is correct

Comment: I think thats a bad idea to start with, dealing with time that way in solidity seems way too complicated to me (time zones, leap seconds... have to be accounted for and i dont see any way of doing it). If i were you i would rethink my contract design

Comment: Take care and analyse which way requires more computational power 'cause the transaction cost. You can try the 2 ways on remix or something similar...